# Informar ou não a View dentro do controller em php?

Tags: php

Criei um framework para uso próprio, um pouco para entendimento de como funciona um fw, mas acabou se transformando em uma ferramenta básica de trabalho. Sei que muitos vão dizer que não se deve tentar reinventar a roda. Mas não estou tentando fazer isso, estou apenas querendo aprender como fazer a roda.

A minha idéia é colocar o nome do controller como pasta da minha view, e o método dentro do controller como o arquivo.

Pra exemplificar:

```
class Home {

public function login() {
//aqui iria meu código
}
```

Nesse caso, meu sistema procuraria na pasta views a pasta **HOME** e dentro da pasta, procuraria o arquivo **LOGIN** dentro dela ( ficaria views/HOME/LOGIN.view.php ).

A dúvida é: Em quais situações eu poderia ter transtornos no sistema? Lembrando que, caso eu queira ter diversos controllers e apenas uma url, basta setar nesses controllers a url, caso nao setar, ele vai buscar por padrao o nome do controlller e o método, como citado acima.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que quem falar que é besteira e que esta reinventando a roda não tem conhecimento sobre o assunto, muitas vezes é melhor trabalhar com um framework próprio que trabalhar vom mais robustos e nao saber usa-lo adequadamente, ou não usar nem a meade dos recursos dele e ter vários arquivos inúteis no sistema.

**caso eu queira ter diversos controllers e apenas uma url**

Sinceramente não entendi o que quer dizer isso, pois como iria definir qual controller, model e view iria chamar?

Normalmente o padrão é: dominio.org/controller/metodo/parametros

Só se seus parâmetros fossem com o método post, dai a url sempre ficaria: dominio.org, porém não acho isso legal, pois o usuário ficaria meio pedido e se o site tivesse uma opção de compartilhar não funcionaria bem.

Agora, sobre a pergunta em si, o único transtorno possível seria se a view respectiva daquele método não existisse,você teria de tratar o erro e outro empecilho seria se um método público não tivesse uma view, como normalmente acontece com o método apagar.

Caso queria fazer essa chamada de view automática sugiro que criei também um método para que o desenvolvedor possa definir uma visão diferente para o método, caso ele não chamar esse método então voce chama o método que define a visão padrão. E deixe um método também para a view poder ser desabilitada naquele método, para ser usado quando o método normalmente não tem uma visão, como o apagar.

Não vejo mais problemas que isso pode causar.